# Is there a way I can record when the stderr is printed to a log file?

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm running the command

```
php someFile.php 1>> stdout.txt 2>> stderr.txt
```

Is there a way I can record when the stderr is printed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507674/how-to-add-timestamp-to-stderr-redirection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excellent question, I didn't know how to pipe `stderr` but I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout).

Then, when you've got your `stderr` piped, you can just replace every beginning of line (`^`) by the message you want. Here I called the `date` command to display the time.

```
php someFile.php 2>&1 >> stdout.txt | sed "s/^/`date +'Error received the %d:%m:%y at %H:%M:%S : '`/" >> stderr.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this book on the [Linux Command Line](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fxx32be06pc8xue/TLCL-09.12.pdf) a lot of good info.