# How to detect when a background command prints to stderr?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have this (partial) script to record audio:

```
#!/bin/sh
...
echo Recording to "$REC_FILE"
arecord [options] > "$REC_FILE" &
ARECORD_PID=$!

SYNC_COUNT=1
while kill -0 "$ARECORD_PID" > /dev/null 2>&1
do
        sleep 1
#        echo $SYNC_COUNT seconds
        sync
        SYNC_COUNT=$(($SYNC_COUNT+1))
done
echo Recording to "$REC_FILE" has ended.
```

which is called with `record.sh >> "$LOGFILE" 2>&1 &`

The reason for the 1-second `<number> seconds` report is because `arecord` doesn't print any timing information with its error messages on `stderr`.  So with just that to go on, I have to look through or listen to an entire recording that might be several hours long to try and find what may or may not be a problem.

I fixed that immediate issue by printing the 1-second counter to the same logfile so that the error message ends up with a crude timestamp above and below it in the file, but that really clutters things up because it's *always* running, even when things are working just fine.

How can I add the present value of that counter to `arecord`'s error messages in the logfile without always spewing that counter, and without messing up the audio recording on stdout [like this answer would appear to do](https://askubuntu.com/a/135023/321777)?  (or does it?)

In other words, instead of this in the logfile, with the counter report uncommented:

```
Recording to rec.wav
1 seconds
2 seconds
3 seconds
4 seconds
...
5093 seconds
arecord hiccuped but is still running
5094 seconds
...
10283 seconds
10284 seconds
Recording to rec.wav has ended.
```

I want something like this:

```
Recording to rec.wav
At 5093 seconds, arecord hiccuped but is still running
Recording to rec.wav has ended.
```

The exact format of the timestamp doesn't matter, or even if it's on the same line, just as long as I still have the original error message and the time relative to the start of recording that it happened.

Comment: Since you redirected stderr for the script, it was redirected for the `arecord` command as well, and anything it outputs to stderr will show up in $LOGFILE. If you don't want that, just redirect its stderr separately: `arecord ... 2>some-other-file &`

Comment: @muru:  I want that error message in the logfile as well, so I know what to look for when I inspect the recording later.  But I also want the logfile to tell me, without extra clutter, what time to look at in that recording.  `arecord` doesn't do that - just prints a message with no time information - hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the `ts` utility](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ts.1.html) (from the `moreutils` package) to timestamp output:

```
If the -i or -s switch is passed, ts timestamps incrementally instead.
In case of -i, every timestamp will be the time elapsed since the last
timestamp. In case of -s, the time elapsed since start of the program
is used.  The default format changes to "%H:%M:%S", and "%.S" and "%.s"
can be used as well.
```

So, run:

```
record.sh |& ts -s >> "$LOGFILE"
```

Comment: Well, I think I actually want to use `arecord [options] > "$REC_FILE" 2>&1 | ts -s >> &2 &` inside of `record.sh` (if I got all that right - I had to google `|&` to see that it expands to that) because there's some other stuff in there that I'd rather not have timestamps on.  I'm a little nervous about that redirection structure because my recording goes through `stdout` and I really don't want to mess that up.  Does this actually pipe `stderr` *without* interfering with where I've sent `stdout`?  And does it continue to put the original error message from `stderr` into the logfile as well?

Comment: @AaronD you can use process substitution (bash, not sh): `arecord ... > "$REC_FILE" 2> >(ts -s >&2)`

Comment: Umm, could you please explain that?  I think you're adding `2> >(ts -s >&2)` to the end of what I had originally, which sends the original `stderr` (`2>`) into `ts` and puts the result back on `stderr` (`>&2`).  But why the parenthesis and the space in `2> >`?  And does `$!` still have `arecord`'s PID in it, or is it `ts`'s now?  And does it really matter for the sole purpose of looping until it ends?

Comment: @AaronD look up "process substitution"

Comment: I did, and got http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html, which only covers the `>()` part as far as I can tell, with lots of complex examples.  So I got the parens now, but the rest is still beyond me.

Comment: @AaronD the rest?

Comment: Okay, I think I got the space now, just by thinking about it.  `2>` puts `stderr` into the next thing on the command line, which in this case is the process substitution, where it shows up as the subbed command's `stdin`.  That command does what it does, and then we can redirect its `stdout` somewhere, which in this case is back to the original `stderr`.

Comment: So all that's left now is whether the PID in `$!` has remained unchanged after all that.  I think it does, unless perhaps there was an immediate error from `arecord`, in which case it might be `ts`'s PID instead, which I certainly don't want.

Comment: I started a new question for the PID problem: http://askubuntu.com/q/873612/321777