# When commands are combined in the background, how to get the "base" command's process identifier?

Tags: command-line, bash

For example:

```
printstuffslowly | ts -s &
ARECORD_PID=$!
```

or:

```
arecord [options] > ~/recording.wav 2> >(ts -s > ~/errors.log) &
ARECORD_PID=$!
```

From my tests on the command line, `$ARECORD_PID` ends up with `ts`'s PID in it.  But what I think I want is `printstuffslowly`'s PID or `arecord`'s PID so that I can loop some more commands until it exits:

```
while kill -0 "$ARECORD_PID" > /dev/null 2>&1
do
        sleep 1
        sync
done
```

Is there a way to get that?  Or does `ts`'s PID actually work just as well for my purpose?

Comment: It turns out that my two examples are different.  The first one gets `ts`'s PID as I mentioned above, while a reformat of the same command to `printstuffslowly > >(ts -s) &` gets `printstuffslowly`'s PID as muru says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will still be the PID of `arecord`. From [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_0024_0021):

> ($!) Expands to the process ID of the job most recently placed into
>   the background, whether executed as an asynchronous command or using
>   the `bg` builtin

The command in process substitution needs to be started before the backgrounded command:

> When available, process substitution is performed simultaneously with
>   parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic
>   expansion.

So that PID is essentially lost (you can still `pgrep` it, but no bash builtin command or variable will get it).

Comment: Okay, there's a lot going on there apparently, because my two examples (edited just before your answer) turned out to work differently.  The one I'm concerned about though looks like exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @AaronD pipes and process substitutions are different. Obviously the last command in the pipe is the last command backgrounded. I don't know why you want to use it when you only want to process stderr and not stdout.

Comment: @AaronD in any case, it shouldn't matter whether you use the PID of `arecord` or `ts` when using pipes - if `arecord` dies, `ts` will also die because the pipe is closed when `arecord` dies.

Comment: I was just going for a more general example because I figured that since I didn't know about process substitution before then not everyone else would either.  And I ended up confusing myself even more.